# Compiz eat up my entire CPU after updating to 15.04

Tags: ati, compiz, multiple-monitors, 15.04

I have this problem only when I use my laptop with an external monitor (this is the way I used to use it). So every time I start my laptop with the external monitor connected, it is unusable. When starting with the built in monitor, it works perfectly.
I tried to follow [this](http://followthegeeks.com/compiz-is-consuming-too-much-cpu-heres-the-solution/) tutorial but it worked until the first restart.

My laptop is an old DELL inspiron 1521 with an ATI GPU.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?